Changed TL072 to OPA2134 - high shelf cut on highs
So I've changed TL072 op-amp to OPA2134 on ART Tube MP V3 preamp.  Everything is working except it appears that high-shelf cut is being created (~9 dB at 10 kHz)  (measured with pro audio interface using REW).
Could anyone help me troubleshoot which part/cap might have brought this problem?  I'm thinking of 100 pF cap (C11) across in/out of op-amp, but I'm not sure.
Here is the device schematic:

Not entirely sure but 90% positive it's U2 that was changed

U2 is shown as an NE5532, not a TL072. Was this "OPA2134" sourced from a reliable supplier?

You'll need to trace every stage to find the cut in the top shelf response or remarkable reduction in square wave risetime >= 5us.
